# Dragging multiple button views in java

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop

I have an app where I need to move stacks of buttons (just like moving part of a stack of cards from one pile to another). I have defined all the buttons in an xml layout and setup touch and drag listeners for all.
I can drag and drop any button around the screen individually. but what I need to do in some cases is drag the other buttons stacked on top of the original button I clicked at the same time. 
Is there a way to "trick" or simulate that another button is pressed (so the listener registers it)?
Thanks
        ***Edited 9/8/15
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        // tosty("mclicking: "+mClicking);
        int startpos = 0;
        switch (e.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        isWastePile=false;

        get_selected_deck(v); // determines which of 7 decks or layouts in the tablau you have
                                // clicked
        FromDeck = selecteddeck;
        FromDeckCard = deckcard;
        FromDeckButton = deckbutton;
        // if (!mClicking) {
        mClicking = true;
        //String piecetag = (String) v.getTag();

        // // IDEA!!!/ ///
        /*
         * I wrote a function that finds all the ImageButtons below where
         * the user clicked, and set them all to invisible. I then created a
         * new Linear Layout within the Linear Layout that the user clicked (during the ACTION_DOWN event),
         * and passed that into the Drag Shadow builder during the ACTION_MOVE event.
         * 
         * Once into the ACTION_DROP portion, I simply referenced global
         * variables to figure out if the user dropped in one or multiple
         * ImageButtons, and dealt with them accordingly.
         */

        //if (!isWastePile) {
        //draglayout.setClipChildren(false);
        lltemp = new LinearLayout(this);
        lltemp.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams llparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        llparams.setMargins(0, -52, 0, 0);
        lltemp.setLayoutParams(llparams);
        draglayout.addView(lltemp);


        for (int i = 0; i < deckstack_list[selecteddeck].size(); i++) {
            if (v == (draglayout.getChildAt(i))) {
                startpos = i;
                for (int o = i; o < deckstack_list[selecteddeck].size(); o++) {
                    // layout5.removeViewAt(o);
                    draglayout.getChildAt(o).setVisibility(View.GONE); // all
                                                                            // buttons
                                                                            // being
                    dragtempstack.push((Integer) deckstack_list[selecteddeck].get(o))   ;                                                   // dragged
                                                                            // to
                                                                            // invisible
                    // then recreate another linear layout within layout5
                    // and pass to dragshadow builder
                    // to do

                    // also set a GLOBAL variable with stack count (number
                    // of cards dragged)
                    lltemp.setClipChildren(false);
                    lltemp.addView(createtempButtons(o, startpos));


                }

            }
        }
        //} // end if wastepile check statement

        //tosty("dragtempstack size: "+dragtempstack.size());

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        //tosty("Action MOVE");
        Log.i("ACTION Event: ", "ACTION MOVE");
        // v = layout5;


        v = lltemp;


        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        v.bringToFront();
        v.invalidate();
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        DeckDragShadow shadowBuilder = new DeckDragShadow(v);
        v.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, v, 0);


        correctDrag = false;

        break;

    private Button createtempButtons(final int i, final int startpos) {
    final Button b = new Button(this);

    b.setOnTouchListener(this);
    b.setOnDragListener(new DeckDragListener());

    b.setBackgroundResource(cardimagearray[dragdeckstack.get(i)]);

    float width = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            45, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    float height = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            61, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            (int) width, (int) height);
    float margTop = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            -36, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    if (i > startpos) {
        params.setMargins(0, -57, 0, 0);
    }

    b.setLayoutParams(params);

    // b.bringToFront();
    // b.invalidate();
    b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return b;
```

Comment: to clarify further, solitaire is a good example of what I need to do. click on a card anywhere in the stack of cards and drag all cards on top of the original button that was clicked. I can change the backgrounds,visibility, etc of all other cards with a loop, but just can't seem to drag all of them.

Comment: I assume you already have something to move a View, so why not, instead of moving a Button, create and move a Layout with the Buttons in it?

Comment: yes, correct I have buttons in a linear layout. If I pass the linear layout view into the drag shadow builder all the buttons will move. but when I try to re-create a temporary linear layout with just the buttons I want the move, for example half of the pile, I run into issues with the drag. Here is some code that I have been trying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than trying to replicate the listeners for each button, I would consider the buttons as groups. When you click on a button within a group, it splits into two groups: the button with the buttons above it and what you are leaving behind. The group is then dragged and dropped onto other groups.

The groups could be LinearLayouts as Templerschaf suggests:

- You click the LinearLayout
- It registers which item
- Makes a new LinearLayout containing the items below that item in the correct position
- Deletes the items below the clicked item and resizes accordingly
- Then the layout can continue to be dragged
- It can then be dropped on another LinearLayout, which will add the items to its own list

This is quite like ListView animations. See:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwE61B56pVQ

https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview/blob/master/library/src/com/mobeta/android/dslv/DragSortListView.java

Comment: I somewhat follow what you mean, I get stuck after creating the new LinearLayout (the dragshadow does not update with the new layout) since I am already clicking the button, which starts the process you suggested, of 1. clicking the layout, 2. I detect/register which button, 3. I create a new temp linear layout with the buttons on top attached and pass that into the dragshadow, but how do I get the image to update with the new linear layout while I am still touching the button? During the drag it still only drags the original button I clicked.

Comment: Once I finish the drag, the new linearlayout is drawn to the screen. I need this all too happen on first press or long press just before the drag. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: You probably want to set clickable as false on the Button and row layout containing the button so that the LinearLayout is handling the drag. You need to respond to both the initial click and the drag separately so you may need onTouchEvent. I think that this is done in the first video I linked to. I'm not convinced that you need to create a BitmapDrawable as is done in that video: it should be possible with a LinearLayout.

Comment: Thanks for all the help,  I finally got something to work, maybe not ideal, performance will tell if I will keep this method. but the biggest difference was in the onTouch method, I split the 2 actions of creating another layout, and creating a dragshadow with the new layout. I used the ACTION_DOWN event to perform all the creating and removing of views, etc. then in the ACTION_MOVE section I passed the newly created layout into the dragshadow builder.

Comment: then with a few extra commands, like bringToFront (new layout was coming in behind pre-existing images), and invalidate() to redraw. I can now drag and drop multiple images from one layout to another.

Comment: Follow up. So I have been encountering a glitch, where every now and then, the new linear layout I created for dragging goes invisible. all the data is still valid and I can still the drop the "invisible" layout to another spot and then it is drawn. for the life of me I can't figure out why this happens randomly.

Comment: You use switching views between VISIBLE, INVISIBLE and GONE quite a lot in the code you use. You could try removing and replacing these one by one to see which is not behaving as you expect it to. Is there a part of the view being clicked that causes the error more often? This might indicate to you what is happening. The error could happen when you are clicking an edge or an area that is part of the layout but not a button.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have begun to do what you suggested without success yet. I have played with different touch points also, does not seem to affect it much. so tough to zero in because it happens about 50% of the time. would be much easier if it was all the time. The search continues. I will post once I find something.